# How to query and display a list of nested tags for a particular parent on front end as links?

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-component, tags, mvc

What is the best way of querying the db to generate a list of tags matching a particular parent and display on the front end as a link with tag title and id?

This is for a custom joomla mvc component which uses two joomla tag fields: "categories" and "collection".

Once I have the list of tags I will then pass the tag id as a variable back to the page with jinput to limit the results in the components list view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To generate a list of tags you can take [getTagTreeArray()](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/libraries/cms/helper/tags.php#L639) method from `JHelperTags` class as a base and modify it for you needs - you can populate the resulting array not only with the IDs, but also with the tag names. Then on frontend you can use [getTagRoute()](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/components/com_tags/helpers/route.php#L78) method of `TagsHelperRoute` class to get the tag link.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can you please vet the late post below?  It seems like a thoughtful answer, but I don't know enough on this subject to differentiate good practice from bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die; // Joomla
$parent_tag_id=12345; // your tag id here
JLoader::register('TagsHelperRoute', JPATH_BASE . '/components/com_tags/helpers/route.php');
$tags_tree=JTable::getInstance('Tag', 'TagsTable')->getTree($parent_tag_id);
// Show children:
foreach($tags_tree as $tags_tree_id=>$tags_tree_item) {
    echo 'DEBUG: ';
    echo ' id:'    . $tags_tree_item->id;
    echo ' level:' . $tags_tree_item->level;
    echo ' path:'  . $tags_tree_item->path;
    $link=TagsHelperRoute::getTagRoute($tags_tree_item->id . ':' . $tags_tree_item->path);
    echo ' link: ' . JRoute::_( $link, true, 1);
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Additonally, to get all parent tag ordered form root to current depth level:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die; // Joomla
$tag_id=12345; // your tag id here
$parent_tags=JTable::getInstance('Tag', 'TagsTable')->getPath($tag_id);
// Show parents and self:
foreach($parent_tags as $parent_tags_id=>$parent_tags_item) {
    echo 'DEBUG: ';
    echo ' id:'        . $parent_tags_item->id;
    echo ' level:'     . $parent_tags_item->level;
    echo ' path:'      . $parent_tags_item->path;
    echo ' published:' . $parent_tags_item-->published;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Please note: you might need to check the published property, as you will get *all* tags, even the trashed ones. 1 is published, 0 is hidden, -2 is trashed, 2 is archived.

See https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Router.Route.html also.